# Edit Existing PDF multiple page File using FPDF & FPDI

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am usinf FPDI to edit my existing pdf file and its work perfect for single page.
As ou can see i am editing my `$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);` first page.
I have six page pdf file and need to add 2 variable in different page.

Is is possible ? How?

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the sourcefile
$pdf->setSourceFile('ex.pdf');

// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);


// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(50, 50);
$pdf->Write(0, "Ajay Patel");

$pdf->Output('newpdf1.pdf', 'D');
?>
```

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: @JA I have imported 6 page pdf file and output is single page, i want all page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's hard to try without FPDI installed. But the core idea would be following I believe:

```
<?php

  require_once('fpdf.php');
  require_once('fpdi.php');

  // initiate FPDI
  $pdf = new FPDI();

  /* <Virtual loop> */
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->setSourceFile('ex.pdf');
  $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

  $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);

  // now write some text above the imported page
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
  $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
  $pdf->SetXY(50, 50);
  $pdf->Write(0, "Ajay Patel");

  /* </Virtual loop/> */

  $pdf->AddPage();
  //$pdf->setSourceFile('ex.pdf');
  $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(2);

  $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200); // dynamic parameter based on your page

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
  $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
  $pdf->SetXY(50, 50);
  $pdf->Write(0, "Ajay Patel2");

  $pdf->Output('newpdf1.pdf', 'D');
?>
```

If this works you can get rid of the second block of the code and out this on a loop (and dynamic positioning as well).

Comment: Will check it let you know soon

Comment: @J A it is creating a blank PDF. what should i check for this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @J A Your idea works for me

I just posted answer for other to help them

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the sourcefile
$pdf->setSourceFile('newpdf.pdf');

// import page 1
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1);
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) { 
              $tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage($i); 


                     $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 200);
                     $pdf->AddPage();

                     $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
                     $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
                     $pdf->SetFontSize(8);

                     if ($i==3) {
                        $pdf->SetXY(50, 124);
                        $pdf->Write(1, "Ajay Patel");

                        $pdf->SetXY(50, 133);
                        $pdf->Write(1, date("d/m/Y"));
                     }

                     if ($i==4) {
                        $pdf->SetXY(50, 171);
                        $pdf->Write(1, "Ajay Patel");

                        $pdf->SetXY(50, 185);
                        $pdf->Write(1, date("d/m/Y"));
                     }

                }

$pdf->Output('newpdf1.pdf', 'D');
?>
```

Comment: regards, I need to do something similar but using concat: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/
as I could do using the ConcatPdf class?

Answer (score 0):

You should really make use of the return value of setSourceFile to iterate over all pages:

Description

`public int FPDI::setSourceFile ( string $filename )`

Depending on the PDF version of the used document the PDF version of the resulting document will be adjusted to the higher version.

Parameters

```
$filename : string // A valid path to the PDF document from which pages should be imported from
```

Return Values

**The number of pages in the document**