# PDF File to Many PDF files, with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

Is there a way to take one PDF file with lets say 4 pages, and convert it to 4 PDF files (with a PHP library perhaps, as that's what I'm using for my backend).

So each PDF file(4) would correspond to a page in the original file.

The reason I want to do this is to enable commenting per page in the PDF.

Comment: What have tried so far? You could try looking at PDFLib

Comment: use fpdf - https://github.com/lsolesen/fpdf/blob/master/tutorial/tuto1.htm ... and this is a possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721497/edit-existing-pdf-multiple-page-file-using-fpdf-pdfi

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather recommend using `pdftk`. It can split or merge pdf files easily.

From PHP you can call a Linux script that calls the pdftk command line tool, or call it directly.

Hope that helped!

*EDIT*: I said Linux thinking in a Linux hosted web, but pdftk exists for Windows and Mac also.

Comment: Also with pdftk you have Windows command line version also, so no problem there