# pdf cover page creation

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf, fpdf

I am developing a project in codeignitor. Here I want to develop a feature like modify existing pdf.

I have list of pdf files in each file I want to add cover page that is html content and save new pdf.

I am looking around for the solution. Please help me to find best approach to get it done.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply you can use FPDF in CodeIgniter...

refer to: https://github.com/iamfiscus/Codigniter-FPDF

me also using fpdf in my projects...

Comment: is it provide to read content from existing pdf and add cover page and create new pdf?

Comment: i dont know, if we can able to read pdf,, me generating pdf from the values from db,,, ie. dynamically create pdf for invoices, bill, and reports...

Comment: my question is for adding content in existing pdf file.

Comment: k you need to edit the existing pdf, i think there is an additional library fpdfi (in FPDF) for your purpose, it actually used for editing existing pdf.... search for 'edit a pdf using fpdf' u can find it....

Comment: for this file http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
Error : FPDF error: Cannot open pdf.pdf !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pdf from your Html using

http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/42/

then you can refer to some already answered similar questions for merging.

[Merge multiple PDF files into one in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855712/merge-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-in-php)

[Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)

[Edit Existing PDF multiple page File using FPDF & FPDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721497/edit-existing-pdf-multiple-page-file-using-fpdf-pdfi)

Comment: try downloading the zip