# how to add images to multiple pages on pdf and download the full pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I started to work with fpdi with fpdf and I try to add more than one image to multiple pages and in the end, I want to download one PDF with the images over the PDF pages.
The problem is that always just the last PDF downloaded with the last page. Why I can't download one file with all the images?

```php
foreach ($signatures as $signa) {
  $fileContent = file_get_contents('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf','rb');
  $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($fileContent));
  $pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($fileContent));
  $tplId = $pdf->importPage($signa->page);
  $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, 10, 10, 100);
  $pdf->Image('signature.jpg', $signa->position->x, $signa->position->y, $signa->size->width, $signa->size->height);

  if($signa->page === 2) {
    $pdf->Output('D');   
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless you create the PDF as a file then download it after you are done creating it you won't be able to send more than one PDF to the browser.

Comment: ok how can i wait it complete all and then download the full file ? @Dave

Comment: Change your output statement to write to a file then use the appropriate headers and `readfile` to send the newly created file to the browser.

Comment: You don't have an example ? @Dave

Comment: Afraid that's not how SO works. The documentation for FPDF shows the options for `output` and how to send a file to the browser is easily searched for (with Google or here on SO). It's fairly trivial since you appear to have most of what you need already.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723658/10994570) and its work for me.

Solution on my code:

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();
foreach ($signatures as $signa) {
$pdf->AddPage();
$fileContent = file_get_contents('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf','rb');
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($fileContent));
$tplId = $pdf->importPage($signa->page);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplId, 10, 10, 100);
$pdf->Image('signature.png', $signa->position->x, $signa->position->y, $signa->size->width, $signa->size->height);
}
$pdf->Output('newpdf1.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: You should move the `file_get_contents()` outside of the loop! And remove the 2nd parameter. If this is an URI to a local file you should use the local path instead!